# Can a running nodejs application cryptographically prove it is the same as published source code version?

Tags: node.js, security, cryptography

Can a running nodejs program cryptographically prove that it is the same as a published source code version in a way that could not be tampered with?

Said another way, is there a way to ensure that the commands/code executed by a nodejs program are all and only the commands and code specified in a publicly disclosed repository?

The motivation for this question is the following: In an age of highly sophisticated hackers as well as pressures from government agencies for "backdoors" that allow them to snoop on private transactions and exchanges, can we ensure that an application has been neither been hacked nor had a backdoor added?

As an example, consider an open source-based nodejs application like lesspass (lesspass/lesspass on github) which is used to manage passwords and available for use here (https://lesspass.com/#/).

Or an alternative program for a similar purpose encryptr (SpiderOak/Encryptr on github) with its downloadable version (https://spideroak.com/solutions/encryptr).

Is there a way to ensure that the versions available on their sites to download/use/install are running exactly the same code as is presented in the open source code?

Even if we have 100% faith in the integrity of the the teams behind applications like these, how can we be sure they have not been coerced by anyone to alter the running/downloadable version of their program to create a backdoor for example?

Thank you for your help with this important issue.

Comment: Unless you have physical access to the file system of the server in question, you cannot get access to what code it is running.  So, from outside the server, you can't tell what code it is running (for good reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sadly no.

simple as that.

the long version:

you are dealing with the outputs of a program, and want to ensure that the output is generated by a specific version of one specific program

lets check a few things:

can an attacker predict the outputs of said program?

if we are talking about open source programs, yes, an attacker can predict what you are expecting to see and even can reproduce all underlying crypto checks against the original source code, or against all internal states of said program

imagine running the program inside a virtual machine with full debugging support like firing up events at certain points in code, directly reading memory to extract cryptographic keys and so on. the attacker does not even have to modify the program, to be able to keep copys of everything you do in plaintext

so ... even if you could cryptographically make sure that the code itself was not tampered with, it would be worth nothing: the environment itself could be designed to do something harmful, and as Maarten Bodewes wrote: in the end you need to trust *something*.

one could argue that TPM could solve this but i'm afraid of the world that leads to: in the end ... you **still** have to trust something like a manufacturer or worse a public office signing keys for TPMs ... and as we know those would never... you hear? ... **never** have other intentions than what's good for you ... so basically you wouldn't win anything with a centralized TPM based infrastructure

Comment: Thanks. Your examples of vulnerabilities are clear. For the record, by TPM you mean Trusted Platform Modules? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module

Comment: Plus One for the "...you wouldn't win anything with a centralized TPM based infrastructure..."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this cryptographically by having a runtime that checks signatures before running any code. Of course, you'd have to trust that runtime environment as well. Unless you have such an environment you're out of luck - that is, unless you do a full code review.

Furthermore you can sign the build by placing a signature within the build system. The build system and developer access in turn can be audited. This is usually how secure development environments are build. But in the end you need to trust *something*.

If you're just afraid that a particular download is corrupted you can test against an official hash published at one or more trusted locations.